# () { :; }; in user agent on server logs

Tags: linux, webserver

Can anyone tell me what someone is trying to do with the following code in their user-agent:

```
() { :; }; echo Content-type:text/plain;echo;echo;echo M`expr 1330 + 7`H;/bin/uname -a;echo @
```

I have a script that tells me when someone has this or similar in their user-agent - a more dastardly-looking string with () { :; }; in it gets the user blocked from my server

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a straightforward attempt to exploit Shellshock, dumping back at them some test output and the result of `/bin/uname -a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are trying to exploit [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)). If the path they tried (they will usually attempt to guess cgi paths) happened to be vulnerable, the output would contain your uname.

The rest (the text/plain content-type, the M1337H first line and @ final one) are mainly cosmetic touches for the output.
Providing "Content-type:text/plain" will ensure the web server doesn't eat it, and that the uname needs to be inbetween M1337H and @ is probably done to filter out the case where a legitimate non-vulnerable cgi does include the machine uname.

Comment: I wonder, then, if I do a yum update, will it be patched?  or maybe it is already?  I don't know.  How would I know if the server was compromised? Thank you for your response.